# PHP - prepare - execute

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, sqlite3, execute

Уважаемые форумчане! Требуется ваша помощь!

Подскажите, как эффективно и просто решить задачу:

Есть массив (кстати, может заменить на объект?) и две таблицы в базе данных:

```
$massive = [

  'animal' => 'cat',
  'age' => '1',
  'color' => 'gray'

];

$db = new PDO('sqlite:file.sqlite');

$db -> exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'table1' (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,

  animal TEXT,
  age INTEGER

)");

$db -> exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'table2' (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,

  animal TEXT,
  color TEXT

)");

$prepare1 = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO 'table1' (animal, age) VALUES (:animal, :age)");
$prepare2 = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO 'table2' (animal, color) VALUES (:animal, :color)");
```

***Цель:*** **записать массив в обе таблицы**. Вроде просто и не было бы вопроса, если бы можно было этот массив отдать в execute и он сам взял что ему необходимо, но насколько я знаю, больше чем нужно параметров нельзя указывать.

**Прошу учесть, что задача упрощена!** В таблицах куча колонок, а не по две как здесь, поэтому их перечисление трудоёмко, это и заставляет искать иные способы!

Comment: А сложность в чем ? идете foreach по массиву и для каждой строки вызываете execute для обоих запросов, передавая массив с параметрами. точнее в вашем случае в массиве только один набор параметров, так что циклы не нужны. просто делаете `$prepare1->execute($massiv);`

Comment: @Mike, обратите внимание что в массиве для обоих запросов есть одно лишнее поле (ну в реальной задаче их больше намного), а в документации php сказано что указание execute лишних аргументов вызовет ошибку, так что не всё так просто

Comment: тогда руками делаем bind_param для нужных в конкретном запросе аргументов. заодно можем правильные типы данных указать. Ну или делаем отфильтрованные массивы только с нужными аргументами

Comment: @Mike, этого ответа я и боялся услышать. То есть никакого автоматического способа решения (без перечисления полей вручную) нет?